# Experimenting with Task.Delay with small times. Trying to find why this happens as it is

Tags: c#, timedelay

Trying to understand how to use Task.Delay I have been doing a series of simple experiments and I have found the following.

First I did this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Start");
     Task.Run(async () => {
                    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                 //    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                  //         await Task.Delay(2);
                     sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Delay of {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                   //return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                });

    Console.WriteLine("End of everything:");
    Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

The result was as expected a delay of a little more than 2 secs. So far so good! 
Then I commented the delay line and uncommented the for loop. 1000 times 2 ms must give 2 secs right? Wrong! it took 15 seconds this time.

I'll comment about this later but just for comparison I did this.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Start");
     Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
          Thread.Sleep(2);

//         Thread.Sleep(2000);
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("Delay of {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
      Console.WriteLine("End");

    }
```

In this case I got a more exact 2 secs and with the for loop something near 2 secs. So this is *NOT* something that happens with `Thread.Sleep` but only with `Task.Delay`

Now, in the documentation it is written

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if the millisecondsDelay argument is less than the resolution of the system clock, which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems.

So there it is! the 15 seconds reason!

*Another* observation I got was that if I put a single Task.Delay with 2000 I got a consistent delay of 2 or 2.1 secs but if I put a single Task.Delay of 2 (not a for loop) the delays varies wildly from run to run. Going from exactly 2ms to 15ms and everything in between

End of my experiments.

My question would be, is there any way I can delay for small milliseconds time? or it is entirely impossible? Any comment on this that can enlarge my comprehension of Task.Delay will be greatly appreciated. Comments on the behavior of Task.Delay with small measures will be also appreciated. Please share your knowledge.

Comment: I think you can improve the resolution of the timer using a [High Performance Timer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=high+performance+timers). See also [ClockRes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/clockres) from the always amazing SysInternals.

Comment: @RB my understanding is that the timer (even high performance) would measure with good precision a time lapse. But how to delay it? (I read that Delay is implemented with timers so would I have to reimplement it?

Comment: What *problem* will be solved by being able to perform thousands of these tiny delays? It's likely that you're coming at your overall problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think you are right. But this let me discover that I can not call -not thousands but - one tiny delay either. So it was a good experimental way to find out something else. Now the thing is that the tiny delays -even one- is not consistent

Comment: You will need to implement your own version of `Task.Delay` using one of the better resolution timers.

Comment: `Now the thing is that the tiny delays -even one- is not consistent` - That's normal. As you stated yourself the timer on Windows is 15.6ms as it's not a real time OS (RTOS). Anything requiring such a precise measurement of time is always a special case.

Answer (score 5):

About [Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx):

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. ... Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses.

And about [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_) :

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if the millisecondsDelay argument is less than the resolution of the system clock, which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems.

So both methods do *not* promise any real-time guarantees, and are heavily dependent on your systems hardware and the load from other processes.

Note for instance that when the thread-pool is overtaxed, it could take up to 500 ms before a new Thread is allocated.

And Windows just isn't a RTOS, all this happens in a context of time-slices and GC runs.